# SQL Server Management Studio - how to find out how a temporary table is created?

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2014

I try to find out how a certain temporary table is created in SQL Server Management Studio because some datas in this table are incorect so I need to fix it, but I can't get to the procedures that creates this table. I recently started working on this database so I don't know how the procedures and tables are related between them...so any hints will be very helpful !
Thank you !

Comment: Start a profiler trace. Alternatively, if you know the table is created in a stored procedure but you don't know which one, try `SELECT * FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE [definition] LIKE '%#temptable%'`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to graphically "see" a temporary table. If you know the name of the temporary table you can write a normal query to see the content, something like:

```
select * from #mytemporarytable
```

Comment: What i want to see is how this table is created...if i have a Name and a Phone column, I want to know where these columns are extracted from and when my temp table updates these values.

Comment: I'm afraid that if you want to know from where the data in the temporary table comes from, then you must find the stored procedure or the query that created it. Probably @Jeroen Mostert's comment contains the best try.